# How to do the paging on my page of blogs?

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I have a page which show the all the posts. I have used the following code.

```
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 0 );
$lastposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach($lastposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The above code displays all the posts on my page.

But Now I want to to do the pagination on this page, to show 3 blog posts per page.

How will I do this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are using this weird structure instead of [the loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)
Try making it into the loop in comibation with [query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)
After that try [posts_nav_link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/posts_nav_link), maybe this works now but I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Page Navi](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pagenavi/) plugin and change from get_posts to query_posts or you can use this stack answer [Paginating get_posts() in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389385/paginating-get-posts-in-wordpress) Thanks